# how to change text color of PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, autocomplete, fragment, google-places-api, textcolor

I'm using the `Theme.AppCompat` for my activity, and it makes the text in the PlaceAutocompleteFragment hard to read. How do i change the color of the text in here?

[image]